# Writing data to fork pipe does not work

Tags: c, linux, shell, fork, pipe

I have the following code in which I use fork to launch my script. The script is listening on the stdin. I try to send data via pipe to myscript but the scipt did not get the data from C. Am I missing something in my code?

```
static int pfds_in[2], pfds_out[2];

void external_init()
{
    int pid;

    if (pipe(pfds_in) < 0)
        return;

    if (pipe(pfds_out) < 0)
        return;

    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        goto error;

    if (pid == 0) {
        /* child */
        close(pfds_in[0]);
        dup2(pfds_in[1], 1);
        close(pfds_in[1]);

        close(pfds_out[0]);
        dup2(pfds_out[1], 0);
        close(pfds_out[1]);

        const char *argv[5];
        int i = 0;
        argv[i++] = "/bin/sh";
        argv[i++] = fc_script;
        argv[i++] = "--json";
        argv[i++] = "json_continuous_input";
        argv[i++] = NULL;
        execvp(argv[0], (char **) argv);
        exit(ESRCH);
    }
    close(pfds_in[1]);
    close(pfds_out[1]);
    return;

error:
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


static void external_write_pipe_output(const char *msg)
{
    char *value = NULL;
    int i=0, len;
    asprintf(&value, "%s\n", msg);
    if (write(pfds_out[0], value, strlen(value)) == -1) {
        perror("Error occured when trying to write to the pipe");
    }
    free(value);
}

int main()
{
    external_init();
    external_write_pipe_output("any");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mismatched the both file descriptors you get from [pipe()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe). `pfds_in[0]` is for reading, so you have to use `dup2( pfds_in[0], 0 )` in your child and in the parent you write into the pipe using `pfds_in[1]`.

Btw: What did you want to achieve by `dup( ..., 1 )` in your child?. If you want to redirect child's stdout into a pipe to your parent you have to create another pipe

Comment: `dup( ..., 0 )` for stdout and `dup( ..., 1 )` for stdin see this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543589/how-to-write-to-the-pipe-fork)

Comment: OK, I didn't look correctly. But you will always need `pfds_...[0]` to dup `0` and `pfds_...[1] to dup `1`

Comment: He is using two pipes actually, but yeah, MOHAMED switch  dup2(pfds_out[1], 0); to  dup2(pfds_out[0], 0); and write(pfds_out[0]... to write(pfds_out[1]

Answer (score 0):

You've got your pipe ends in a muddle.

In the child you should have:

```
close(pfds_in[0]);
dup2(pfds_in[1], 1);
close(pfds_in[1]);

close(pfds_out[1]);
dup2(pfds_out[0], 0);
close(pfds_out[0]);
```

And in the parent:

```
close(pfds_in[1]);
close(pfds_out[0]);
```

Comment: and to write to the pipe? I have to use: `write(pfds_out[0],...)` or `write(pfds_out[1],...)` ?